# On hover button, visiability:visible is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

On hover button, if we inspect whatever the code written it is showing  but if we remove inspect element it is not showing that hover effects. Please refer my code and give me valuable suggestions that why my code is not working properly. Please give me the suggestion.

```css
.desc-btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: #00BCD4;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.desc-btn:hover {
  color: #00bcd4 !important;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #00bcd4;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-description">
  <p class="text-center"><b>BOSE</b> Headset</p>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/welcome/item">
    <p class="desc-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Supplier</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using hover on `a` tag: `.product-description a:hover .desc-btn {}`

```css
.desc-btn{
  color: #fff;
  background: #00BCD4;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 15px;
  position:relative;
  bottom:30px;
  left:0px;
  visibility:hidden;
}
.product-description a:hover .desc-btn {
  color: #00bcd4 !important;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #00bcd4;
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-description">
  <p class="text-center"><b>BOSE</b> Headset</p>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/welcome/item">
    <p class="desc-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Supplier</p></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this code is not working as per our requirements.

Comment: So, that create a demo what you want and so other are able to show what's problem are coming

Answer (score 0):

Try document.GetElementById or document.querySelector(".desc-btn").hide() and same thing for hover except do .show() at end. There is also display: block;

Answer (score 0):

```
This i has done.    
<div class="imgage-description">
          <b><p>Product Name</p></b>
          <span>Product Description</span><br/>
          <span>Supplier Name</span><br/>
          <a href="<?php // echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/contact"> 
              <button class="btn desc-btn" title="Contact Supplier"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Supplier</button> 
          </a>
          </div>


<script>
     $('.desc-btn').hide();
    $('.product-display').mouseenter(function(){

       $( this ).find('.desc-btn').show();

    });
     $('.product-display').mouseleave(function(){

        $( this ).find('.desc-btn').hide();

    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hover` through anchor tag and also add a `display:block` property to anchor tag.

```css
.desc-btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: #00BCD4;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.product-description a {
   display: block;
}
.product-description a:hover .desc-btn {
  color: #00bcd4 !important;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #00bcd4;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-description">
  <p class="text-center"><b>BOSE</b> Headset</p>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/welcome/item">
    <p class="desc-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Supplier</p>
  </a>
</div>
```